# OOP Approach To Buffering Data In Network App

Tags: c++, oop, networking, composite

I am working on a network library for Ethernet\IP.  I am looking for input on good design strategies to assemble my packets to send them out.  I am using a composite pattern to represent the pieces of my packet because I feel it well represents the underlying protocol. CIP is very object based.  My issue is that using a composite pattern means my data is fragmented into small pieces and I need to assemble it to send encapsulating each piece with some data.  I have also been reading alot about good design strategies for network programming and they suggest not dynamically allocating memory more then needed.

A side note I am also open to using boost in this application so I have thinking of using Asio

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The manner you compose your transport is directly dependent upon the environment (read: how stable the connection, etc) and goals (security, performance, resilience, etc).

You'll likely find [the open-source Poco libraries](http://pocoproject.org/) worthy of review (if you've not already), as there are some valuable samples and design patterns described.